# Copying the values in a column based in their index referencing the value of other DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm having a problem with creating a new column based from value of my df2["index"]. What I want to get is the value inside df1["score"] based from its actual index.

It make it more understandable, here's my two sample dataframes:

```
df1= pd.DataFrame({'cluster':[1,2,3,4,5], 'score':[80, 90, 60, 40, 12]})  
df2= pd.DataFrame({'word':["hello", "my", "name", "is", "tom"], 'label':["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee"], 'idx':[1,3,4,4,4]})
```

And here's the result I'm expecting to have where the score is referenced based from the "index" column of df2 and the 'actual index' of df1

```
df3= pd.DataFrame({'word':["hello", "my", "name", "is", "tom"], 'label':["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee"], 'idx':[1,3,4,4,4], 'score':[90, 40, 12, 12, 12]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` df1['score'] matched by index values:

```
df2['score'] = df2['idx'].map(df1['score'])
print (df1)
    word label  idx  score
0  hello    aa    1     90
1     my    bb    3     40
2   name    cc    4     12
3     is    dd    4     12
4    tom    ee    4     12
```